# HTML5 Address Tag for Listing of events

Tags: html

For a listing of events, I was planning on using the [HTML5 Address](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_address.asp) in the markup to show search engines this is a location. I will be displaying 5 upcoming events on the homepage.

Do I put this inside a `section` or `article`?

When I read the HTML5 specification it confuses me, if anybody could explain how to use this better.

Updated with code from Steve:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <h3><a href="<?php echo $event['href']; ?>" title="<?php echo $event['title']; ?>"><?php echo $event['title']; ?></a></h3>
    <p><?php echo $event['description']; ?>         
        <span class="datetime">When: <time datetime="<?php echo $event['start_date']; ?>" pubdate="pubdate"><?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($event['start_date'])); ?></time></span>
        <span class="location">Where: <address><?php echo $event['location']; ?></address></span></p>
</li>
```

Comment: Is it part of an article? No? Then don't put it in an `<article>`.

Comment: Ok, so do I just use the <code>address</code> in a list or not use it at all? Its to hold the address location of events

Comment: Or is there anything more suited I should use?

Comment: if they're going to be a list, wouldn't they already be inside `<li>` tags?

Comment: Yes I would have to put them in a list because I want it to work in IE with JavaScript turned off. 

I just want to know if there are any new HTMl5 attributes that I should be using now with a lift of events

Comment: While W3Schools is dire, they haven't got this bit wrong, `<address>` **defines the contact information for the author or owner of a document**, it does not describe arbitrary physical addresses.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am sorry to say, but in this context you are misusing the `<address>` tag. It is meant to provide contact information for the author(s) of the document, not for arbitrary addresses.

> The address element represents the contact information for its nearest article or body element ancestor. If that is the body element, then the contact information applies to the document as a whole.
>
> The address element must not be used to represent arbitrary addresses (e.g. postal addresses), unless those addresses are in fact the relevant contact information. **(The p element is the appropriate element for marking up postal addresses in general.)**

The spec: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/sections.html#the-address-element

A helpful article: http://html5doctor.com/the-address-element/

Comment: HTML5 has got a whole lot confusing. After reading the link on html5doctor, I will using the <p> with hCard class name's splitting up the different fields of the address. Using this: http://microformats.org/code/hcard/creator.

Thanks

Comment: Happy I could help and interestingly `<address>` was actually around before HTML5. It is not a new element.

Comment: HTML3 I think I read. Really good website link too, I will be reading this massive page tomorrow: http://html5doctor.com/microdata/ seems to cover a lot of the new stuff.

Comment: However, what is prescribed usage and what happens in practice can be different. Yelp.com (as of January 2014) uses the `<address>` tag to mark up addresses on its search results pages listing multiple businesses.  And they use it again when viewing a single business (this time adding microdata info as well).

Answer (score 3):

Just to reiterate what tw16 said, you don't want to be using the `<address>` if you want to keep your code semantic. The tag is used inside an `<article>` to semantically display the author information.

Use `<p>` for your address.

Answer (score 2):

If you're showing multiple items, use a list

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <address>address</address>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing anything new apart from date and address.